# read multi-line column using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below data which contain product_id, date, review seperated by a pipe delimiter. The review however is present in multiple lines.

> B001WAKR3W|2012-03-15|Scroll wheel gears wore out and now the mouse scrolls up when you try to scroll down. Makes using the scroll \ wheel impossible, even for middle clicking. I can't even scroll through a web page. The teeth on the gears are so worn out that it scrolls when I middle click.\
> The rubber grips also fell off the sides of the mouse due to bad glue.\

I want to read this data into a pandas dataframe but the line breaks are creating a separate row in the dataframe.

In the second comment there is a backslash after the word "click" which is causing pandas to consider it into a separate row

how to read this data into a single row even though there are backslashes as line breaks in a single review

Answer (score 0):

To read this data into a pandas dataframe and ensure that the reviews are correctly added as a single row, you can preprocess the data to replace the backslashes with spaces. Here's how you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your data as a list of strings
data = [
    "B001WAKR3W|2012-03-15|Scroll wheel gears wore out and now the mouse scrolls up when you try to scroll down. Makes using the scroll \\ wheel impossible, even for middle clicking. I can't even scroll through a web page. The teeth on the gears are so worn out that it scrolls when I middle click.\\ The rubber grips also fell off the sides of the mouse due to bad glue.\\"
]

# Split the data into columns using the pipe delimiter
data = [line.split('|') for line in data]

# Create a DataFrame from the processed data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['product_id', 'date', 'review'])

# Replace backslashes with spaces within the 'review' column
df['review'] = df['review'].str.replace('\\', ' ')

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Note, that in the data that you have provided, there's an issue with the backslash (`\`) at the end of your data. You cannot add a backslash at the end of a string since it is an escape character in many programming languages, including Python. To fix this issue, you should replace all the back slashes with double back slashes as I have done above or if you still want to use a single backslash, you should remove the backslash at the end of the string.

Output:

```
   product_id        date                                             review
0  B001WAKR3W  2012-03-15  Scroll wheel gears wore out and now the mouse ...
```